# Book where dragon's shadow causes forgetfulness

Tags: story-identification

I've read this book about 10 years ago, an I think it's part of a series of books. It's high fantasy, and I remember that the protagonist is a commoner, perhaps female (but I'm not sure). The main feature I do remember is that when dragons fly, their shadow causes forgetfulness to people it passes over. There is an island/continent separated by sea from the main place where the story is told that dragons live there and the people there are like zombies, completely without memory. The main place (continent) rarely sees dragons and they fear them. I think that during the book the other island/continent is starting invade the main place/continent by stealth (i.e. infiltrating a few at a time).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds a little bit like the Farseer Trilogy by Robin Hobb, though it's not a perfect match.

It's based in a country called the Six Duchies. The land is being attacked by a people resembling Vikings, called the Red Ship Raiders. The raiders take hostages then return them unharmed but turned into a zombie like state - these people are referred to as The Forged. The Forged don't eat brains but they do kill anyone they meet.

The protaganist is a boy called Fitz who is a royal bastard fathered by the Crown Prince on a servant girl. He is taken in by the palace and trained as an assassin.

The rest contains spoilers - you have been warned!

> The dragons are created by people with a power called The Skill. The creator and the dragon merge to form the dragon, and the dragon has some psychic powers that I'm afraid I only dimly remember. At the time of the book this is a forgotten skill, but at the end of the trilogy the king Verity creates a dragon and uses it to defeat the Red Raiders. The dragons do remove memories though again I'm afraid the details have slipped my mind. Indeed the Red Raiders learned how to create The Forged by studying the effects the dragons have on their own people.

Comment: Hmm, that's sounds about right. The "Red Ship Raiders" ring a bell, as well as that they take people hostage and returning them as zombies (kinda). Also the name Fitz sound familiar. I'll find the first book and see if it's what I remember.

Comment: @EliIser Fitz has a friend called molly who is his close friend at the start of the series.  Maybe this is why think the protagonist maybe female? (I am vague on this my self it's a long time since I read it)

Comment: I'm now into the second book, and still no mention of dragons. I'm beginning to wonder where I got that strong impression about them, since I'm pretty sure that I've only read the first book back then. Anyway, this is the book I've been thinking about, thank you very much!

Comment: @EliIser: The dragons first appear in book 3. I won't spoil the fun by saying where :-)

Comment: Just finished the third book. In the last chapter, in one small paragraph there is the thing that I remembered so well - dragon's shadow causing forgetfulness. I swear I've only read the first book back then. Anyway, thank you very much for the correct answer!

Comment: @EliIser: if you're interested Robin Hobb has started a new Farseer trilogy. The first book, [Fool's Assassin](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fools-Assassin-Trilogy-Realm-Elderlings/dp/0553392425), is out now. The rating on Amazon is 4.7 out of 5, and having just read it I'd go along with that.